# Where to look up animal facts concisely

Tags: literature

Googling leads to results such as [this](https://defenders.org/bald-eagle/basic-facts):

> DIET
>   Eagles primarily eat fish, carrion, smaller birds and rodents. Eagles are also known to prey on large birds and large fish.
>
> POPULATION
>   Bald eagle numbers in the U.S. were estimated to be between 300,000-500,000 in the 1700s. Numbers were once as low as 500 nesting pairs in the lower 48 states. Bald eagle numbers have rebounded since and now the lower 48 states boast over 5,000 nesting pairs. There are a total of about 70,000 bald eagles in the whole of North America (Including Alaska and Canada).
>
> RANGE
>   Bald eagles live near bodies of water in Canada and Alaska, and in scattered locations all throughout the lower 48 states and Mexico.

I would like to find something like this but with more detail, perhaps scholarly papers or such like that, like you might find on a synopsis/summary article for a specific protein. Wondering if anything like this exists.

Examples of "facts" I would like to look up:

- food sources
- habitat
- range
- color
- sound
- population size
- lifespan range

Stuff you see like [this](http://www.uwyo.edu/wyndd/_files/docs/reports/speciesassessments/baldeagle-nov2004.pdf) has few if any citations where they get the info from.

Comment: I'd write a program that can query google for complex search terms and return the related numbers, colors, phrases and paragraphs for all 10,000 most common animal species. Then simply press enter and the program could add about 100 species to the database every hour, hammering google.

Comment: @com.prehensible — Gosh! Sounds really easy. You do lot of this sort of thing?

Comment: It's called parsing. It would take literally a week to have a draft version going. I'm not very good at it, I run unity3D which does webURL queries and any code you want from it, it returns text and you just have to use string commands to search, concatenate, divide substrings. I did something like that 4-5 years ago, which builds animated 3D phylogeny trees using google image search.

Comment: @com.prehensible — you need to include the @ handle to alert anyone other than the poster to a comment. This is obviously not the place to discuss computational methods, but parsing free text successfully is a complex task, which I would be surprised to see performed with a gaming engine. And remember that Wikipedia entries are compiled by humans with at least some expertise. Who is going to tell whether pressing “enter” produces garbage or not?